# Why can't cast int to string in LinQ using SqlFunctions?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Why does this `Linq` not work?

```
Groups.Where(x => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?)x.Code)
                              .Trim().StartsWith(txtSearch.Text))
      .ToList();
```

**Error**

```
The specified method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' on the type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.
```

I am using EF6 / SQL CE / C#

Code is a int field

Comment: could you be more specific? what's the exception/error?

Comment: what is the error exception/compiler error you get?

Comment: what is Groups and it's Code property?

Comment: Code is a Int field ,  Groups are a list of Entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `SqlceFunctions` not `SqlFunctions`

So your code should be

```
  Groups.Where(x =>  SqlCeFunctions.StringConvert ((double?) x.Code)
                                   .TrimStart() .StartsWith(txtSearch.Text))
        .ToList();
```

**Namespace**: System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact;